# Get ordernumber on the event sales_order_payment_pay

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get my order number on the event sales_order_payment_pay

But somehow I got nothing .. maybe you can help me ? 
Here is the sample of my code in my Observer.php

```
public function functioninobserver($observer) {
    $orderid = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getIncrementId();
}
```

First of all it returns nothing and I think Incrementid is not the same as orderthe number ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The invoice isn't the same as the order, you can get the order in a slightly roundabout way...

```
$orderId = $observer->getPayment()->getOrder()->getId();
$orderNumber = $observer->getPayment()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

Just to clarify; The order ID is used internally in the database. The order number is what's displayed on screen and looks like `#100000123`.

Comment: wonderful! thanks you very much. I can stop hammering my head on the wall! Hope it will be useful for some poeple :-)